# how to use ehcache in spring mvc with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, ehcache

I am new to spring-mvc and want to integrate ehcache as second level cache in hibernate.
I followed this tutorial [ehcache](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/04/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/)
Now entries in my hibernate.xml are as follows:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</property>
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

entries in ehcache.xml are as follows:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<!--defaultCache
        eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="true"
        timeToLiveSeconds="300"
        statistics="true"
        copyOnWrite="true"
/-->

<cache name="com.payupaisa.cms.model.Event" 
 maxElementsInMemory="100000" 
 eternal="true" 
 overflowToDisk="false"
 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
 statistics="true"
timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
/>

</ehcache>
```

we are following mvc model and in model i defined annootation

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY,
region="department")
```

Now issue is how to start using this cache in service layer.
I have not created hibernateUtil.java in my project. we are having web based spring-hibernate mvc application.
Now how to start , i am not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/configuring-ehcache-with-jpa-hibernate-spring/) shows you an example to integrate Spring + Hibernate + EHCache.